# Select2 does not render items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

My select2 is acting really weird, it opens up but the items are not shown, here are the screenshots
opened
[image: this is when it is opened]

closed
[image: and when it is closed]

my markup is

```
<select id="gender">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

and here is my js code

```
$("#gender").select2({
    theme: "classic",
    placeholder: "Gender",
    allowClear: true,
    width: "100%"
});
```

Tried everything but all its doing is wasting my time and the .select2-results through inspector exists but blank on display, just draws the frame, any help in figuring this out will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1** I put the select on parent html and it was okay but the select is in animatedModal, that's where the problem comes

Comment: So why not just assign it after the modal show call? Like $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $("#gender").select2({.....
})

Comment: Definitely initialise `select2` after modal is opened. The component does work correctly if initialised when hidden.

Comment: my datepicker was also messed up so guess the issue was assigning it before showing the modal